# jquery, issue with mouseEnter and slideToggle

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle, mouseenter

I made a little jquery script, when the mouse is over a div .frame, it is slidetoggleing two divs: .contentTop and .contentBottom
It's working well but I have some issues when I'm applying the script to 2 divs, first when I'm moving really fast the mouse from one div .frame to the other one it mess the script, then when the mouse is over .frame I would like .contentBottom to be over the other.frame

my css are:

```
    .frame{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    width:40%;
}


.contentTop { 
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.contentBottom { 
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    display: none;
}
```

and my jquery:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.frame', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    var hauteur = el.height();
    var largeur = el.width();
    contentBottom = el.children(".contentBottom");
    contentTop = el.children(".contentTop");
    contentTop.css({"bottom":hauteur,"width":largeur}); 
    contentTop.html('top top top top');
    contentBottom.html('bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>');
    contentBottom.css({"top":hauteur,"width":largeur});
    contentBottom.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);
    contentTop.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300);   
}).on('mouseleave','.frame', function() {
    var el = $(this);
    contentBottom = el.children(".contentBottom");
    contentTop = el.children(".contentTop");
    contentTop.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300, function(){
        contentTop.html('');
    });
    contentBottom.stop(true, true).slideToggle(300, function(){
        contentBottom.html('');
    });
});
```

I made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/2ANkq/2/

Comment: Personally, all those decorative css styles just make it so much harder for people to see what could be the problem. They are just so distracting when you are trying to debug. e.g. `border-radius`,`box-shadow`

Comment: ok thanks for your note, I'm editing everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need: **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2ANkq/7/)**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {

    var $el=$(this),
        h = $el.height(),
        w = $el.width(),
        $bott = $el.find(".contentBottom"),
        $top  = $el.find(".contentTop"),
        mEnt  = e.type == "mouseenter"; // boolean

    // this
    $el.stop().animate({borderRadius: mEnt? 0 : 3 });

    // top
    $top.css({bottom: h, width: w, zIndex:1})
        .html('top top top top')
        .stop().slideToggle(function(){
             $(this).css({zIndex:0});
        });

    // bottom    
    $bott.css({top: h, width: w,  zIndex:1})
         .html('bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>bottom bottom bottom bottom<br>')
         .stop().slideToggle(function(){
             $(this).css({zIndex:0});
         });

});
```

<sub>**Note:** `.stop()` method, and `mEnt` boolean variable and it's use with Conditional Operator `statement ? ifTrue : ifFalse`</sub>

Comment: thanks, it's really nice! just one thing, when the mouse is over top .frame so contentBottom is over the other .frame just like I wanted but when the mouse leaves before slideToggleing, the z-index of contentBottom change and now it is under the other .frame

Comment: @user2461031 than you need to use the `slideToggle` callback function. Updated my answer to reproduce the right behavior.

Comment: thanks a lot, i was strugling to try to do it then i saw your edit, really thanks a lot, your code is really nice!

Comment: @user2461031 you're welcome! I strive to make nice and readable code :) I just find and fixed an issue with zIndex (camelcase!)

Comment: I confirm, it's really a nice and readable code, i will learn a lot of things thanks to your code... Thank you...